# How to get accurate result of two double value division if one is divisible by another?

Tags: c++

If one double value is already known divisible by another(that is, a/b gives an integer in mathmatics), how can I get the accurate integer result in C++? [example code](https://godbolt.org/z/cr94vvcd4)

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  double price = 1235.1;
  double step = 0.1;
  // prints 12350, 12351 expected
  std::cout << int(price/step) << std::endl;

  price = 1235.2;
  step = 0.1;
  // prints 12352, ok
  std::cout << int(price/step) << std::endl;
};
```

Comment: don't use floating point numbers for money or prices. However you can do `int( (price+0.5*step)/step)`

Comment: Interesting that `std::cout << std::fmod(1235.1, 0.1) << "\n";` shows `0.1`. :-)

Comment: But note, to see why the result is what it is in my previous comment: `std::cout << std::setprecision(20) << std::fmod(1235, 0.1) << "\n";` shows `0.099999999999931449279`.

Comment: `1235.1` is actually 1235.09999999999990905052982270717620849609375; `0.1` is 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625, and `1235.2` is 1235.200000000000045474735088646411895751953125.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist should Know About Floating-Point](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: A general advice: never truncate floating point to integers before first rounding them. `int(std::round(price/step))` would have worked.

Comment: As people pointed out only fractions of power of 2 are exact representable by floating point numbers. If original case is important an alternative is to use rational numbers. Boost has  a library for this https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/rational/rational.html. Probably using rationales has its own set of liabilities (limited range; performance?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### To answer your *exact question*:

> If one double value is already known divisible by another(that is, a/b gives an integer in mathmatics), how can I get the accurate integer result in C++?

You just divide them by each other exactly as you would naively expect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> //std::setprecision

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::setprecision(20);

    //2^7, aka 128, exactly representable in double precision
    constexpr double price = 2.0*2.0*2.0*2.0*2.0*2.0*2.0; 
    std::cout << price << " = 2.0^7 exact\n";

    //(1/2)^4, aka 1/16, aka 0.0625, exactly representable in double precision
    constexpr double step = 0.5*0.5*0.5*0.5;
    std::cout << step << " = 0.5^4 exact\n";

    //(2^7)/((1/2)^4), exactly representable in double precision
    constexpr double d_result = price/step;
    std::cout << d_result << " = (2^7)/((1/2)^4) exact\n";

    // as an integer
    constexpr int i_result = d_result;
    std::cout << i_result << " = 2048 exact\n";

    //there is no difference between d_result and i_result
    constexpr double difference = d_result - i_result;
    static_assert(difference == 0.0);
}
```

This compiles, so the static assert establishes there is no difference between the integer representation and the double representation.

It prints:

```
128 = 2.0^7 exact
0.0625 = 0.5^4 exact
2048 = (2^7)/((1/2)^4) exact
2048 = 2048 exact
```

### The reason this doesn't work for you:

Your doubles are known to *not* be evenly divisible by each other, because the value of `step` is not 0.1, it is 0.100000001490116119, which is the 64bit floating point number closest to real number 1/10.

If you want exactness like this, use a data type with exact representation, e.g. instead of storing dollars as a double, store cents as an integer. (Or use a library that provides arbitrary precision rational numbers. GMP is a popular choice when LGPL is an acceptable license)

Answer (score 2):

You don't. Floating point numbers are not exact. If you want exact arithmetics do not use floating point numbers. As mentioned in a comment, rather than `float dollars` you can work with `int cents`.

However, conversion to `int` truncates the fractional part, hence, provided `(int)price % (int) step == 0` and both are positive you can get the desired output via:

```
std::cout << int((price+step*0.5)/step) << std::endl;
```